# I need to save clients search in db then check against the saved search

Tags: wordpress, html-select, mls

I am building a real estate site for a customer. I have the mls listings imported into the database. I have crm that is VERY LIMITED. I am looking for a plugin or method to save the customers search so that they can be sent new listings as matching ones become available.

Comment: What was your approach and what challenge are you facing? It's necessary you share that with the community for a better experience!

Comment: I am using the wp-property plugin. This plugin does great (after MUCH coding and mapping) at importing properties into your database. I have tried looking for a plugin that will work with this or even that will just allow me to let users save their search! I have found nothing. So my challenge is finding a way to save registered users search when browsing for properties.

Comment: have you tried any code? Doesnt sound so hard to save a query (I bet u would save it as a string), Why dont you make a user profile matching locations and other types included in the query and trigger a method when new listings are added and match the profile?

Comment: I was hoping someone new of a plugin that did this generally. I was hoping to not have to reinvent the wheel with these guys